# Where is the error [JS DOM HTML]?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want add options to the select with a js function.
But there is a problem on the vector, i think, someone can help me?

```
<html>
<body onload="myFunction()">
<select id="mySelect"></select>
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        var months= ["january","february"];
        var mySelect = document.getElementById('mySelect');
        var newOption = document.createElement('option');
        for(var i=0;i<mesi.length;i++){
             newOption.innerHtml=mesi(i).valueOf;
             mySelect.appendChild(newOption);
        }
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is **mesi** ?

Comment: @RohitasBehera It's 'months' in Italian. OP switched languages mid-function.

Comment: @Froster is the issue solved ?

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to have the wrong array name in the for block.
Also, when you're calling an index in an array - use square brackets - `months[i]`, not parentheses. And using valueOf is unnecessary.

```
    function myFunction() {
var months= ["january","february"];
var mySelect = document.getElementById('mySelect');
var newOption = document.createElement('option');
for(var i=0;i<months.length;i++){ // <- here is where the fix goes.
     newOption.innerHtml=months[i];// <- here is where the fix goes.
     mySelect.appendChild(newOption);
}
}
```